# MySQL Include 0 in count many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I've got a table of areas that have an ID,  a table of noise levels, and a table that records entries that have both an area ID and a noise level. I'm hoping to achieve something that will return a count of all of the areas's noise levels, even if an area has never been recorded as that noise level.

Area:

```
|spaceid|     name|
-------------------
|      1|1st floor|
|      2|2nd floor|
|      3|3rd floor|
```

Noise Level:

```
|noiseid| label|
----------------
|      1|Quiet |
|      2|Medium|
|      3|Loud  |
```

Relationship:

Records:

```
|spaceid|noiseid|
-----------------
|      1|      1|
|      2|      1|
|      3|      1|
|      1|      1|
|      2|      2|
|      3|      2|
|      1|      3|
|      2|      3|
|      3|      3|
```

Query

```
SELECT
    records.spaceid, noise.label, count(records.spaceid)
FROM
    noise
LEFT JOIN
    records on noise.noiseid = records.noiseid
GROUP BY
    records.spaceid,
    noise.noiseid
```

Expected results:

```
|records.spaceid|noise.label|count(records.spaceid)|
----------------------------------------------------
|              1|      Quiet|                     2|
|              1|     Medium|                     0|
|              1|       Loud|                     1|
|              2|      Quiet|                     1|
|              2|     Medium|                     1|
|              2|       Loud|                     1|
|              3|      Quiet|                     1|
|              3|     Medium|                     1|
|              3|       Loud|                     1|
```

Actual Results

```
|records.spaceid|noise.label|count(records.spaceid)|
----------------------------------------------------
|              1|      Quiet|                     2|
|              1|       Loud|                     1|
|              2|      Quiet|                     1|
|              2|     Medium|                     1|
|              2|       Loud|                     1|
|              3|      Quiet|                     1|
|              3|     Medium|                     1|
|              3|       Loud|                     1|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT spaces.spaceid, noises.label, COUNT(records.spaceid)
FROM noises JOIN spaces
LEFT JOIN records 
  ON noises.noiseid = records.noiseid 
     AND spaces.spaceid = records.spaceid
GROUP BY spaces.spaceid, noises.noiseid
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30817/6). The key thing here is making LEFT JOIN over *two* conditions instead of just one - combination of spaceid and noiseid.